# foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**I am trying to insert data by Select users from checkbox's and input different point for each user
but when I submit I got this error**

and is that the correct way to insert multi value coming from checkboxes in the model
with different point for each user

Can someone please help me to find out Where I am wrong?

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('user.action.push')}}" >
@csrf
                <table  class="display table table-bordered table-separated" >
                        <thead>
                         <th scope="row">
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input id="selectAll"  class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="custom-control-label"></span>
                    <span style="background-color:red;" class="custom-control-description sr-only"></span>
                </label>
            </th>

                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>point</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($users as $user)
                            <tr>
  <td scope="row">
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="user_[{{$user->id}}]" value="{{$user->id}}" class="custom-control-input" >
                    <span class="custom-control-label"></span>
                    <span style="background-color:red;" class="custom-control-description sr-only"></span>
                </label>
            </td>

    <td style="color:white">{{$user->name}}</td>

    <td style="color:white">{{$user->email}}</td>

    <td style="color:white"><input type="text" name="point_[{{$user->id}}]" >
</td>
                            </tr>                   
        @endforeach 
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Select</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>point</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.box -->      
            </div>  
<div class="col-3">
             <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Select Action</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">

 <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Select Action <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
        <div class="controls">
            <select  name="action_id"  class="form-control" >

                <option disabled="" selected="">Select Action</option>
@foreach($actions as $action)
                <option value="{{$action->id}}">{{$action->action_title}}</option>
@endforeach
            </select>
            <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary"> send</button>
         </form>
```

**the ActionUserPush function**

```
 public function ActionUserPush(Request $request){
            
       foreach($request->user_id as $user_id){
                $point = $request->point_[$user_id];
    
               ActionUser::insert([
                  
                    'user_id'=>$user_id,
                    'point' =>$point,
                    'action_id'=>$request->action_id,
    
                ]); }
    
            $notification = array(
                'message' => ' Action Activited Successfully',
                'alert-type' => 'success'
            );
            return redirect()->route('user_action_view')->with($notification);}
```

Comment: `$request->user_id` is empty/null. You dont have any  name attribute `user_id[]` on your form

Comment: I can't find any input name `user_id` in your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any input with name`user_id`and in your form you can not define the input name dynamically like you have done. You should have to use a fixed name for it. Change your form input to:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="{{$user->id}}" class="custom-control-input" >
```

Then you can access it by using `$request->user_id`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like below

```
name="user_id[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any input with nameuser_idand in your form you can not define the input name dynamically like you have done. You should have to use a fixed name for it. Change your form input to:

id}}" class="custom-control-input" >
Then you can access it by using $request->user_id